# I need to say whether they form a topology on real

Tags: general-topology

consider the usual topology on real line, given that $$T=\{U\subseteq \mathbb{R}:  \text{$U$ is either open, bounded, empty, or the whole real line}\}$$
and
$$S=\{U\subseteq \mathbb{R}: \text{$U$ is either open, unbounded, empty, or the whole real line}\}.$$

I need to say whether they form a topology over the reals. Well, $\emptyset$ and $\mathbb{R}$ are in both, and as finite intersection and arbitrary union of open sets are open, both are topologies, right?

Comment: I think the first comma (after "open") is to be read as an "and". Is the finite intersection o funbounded sets unbounded? Is the union of bounded sets bounded?

Comment: oooooops I misssed these points

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $T$: Let $A_n = \{n\}$. $A_n$ is bounded, hence $A_n \in T$. However, $\cup A_n \notin T$.

For $S$: We have $\mathbb{Z} \in S$ and $(-1,1) \in S$, but $\mathbb{Z} \cap (-1,1) = \{ 0 \} \notin S$.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming @Hagen is correct, consider the following open sets in $\mathcal S$: Fix $1>\varepsilon>0$
$$
U=(-1,1)\cup\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty(2n,2n+1/2)\\
V=(-1,1)\cup\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty(2n+1,2n+1+1/2).
$$
$U,V$ are clearly unbounded since they run off to infinity. However, their intersection is only $(-1,1)$, so it's not an open, unbounded set, hence $U\cap V$ is not 'open' in $\mathcal S$.

Now in $\mathcal T$, let $U_n=(0,n)$. Each is open and bounded, but their countable union is $(0,\infty)$, which is not bounded.